# Get username that submitted a form in wp contact form 7?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

how can I get the username that submitted a form created with contact form 7?
I know there I can set it as default and hide it, but then users can change it and submit it of course (I need it to be uneditable).

So is there any way I can get in Flamingo plugin the username of the person who submitted the form? Or any suggestion?

I created the form with the plugin editor, so I create the fields like this:

```
<p> Username
    [text* your-name default:user_login] </p>

<label> Email
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> Passaport
    [text* your-subject] </label>
```

And then I use the shortcode to insert the form:

```
[contact-form-7 id="127" title="Formulario de contacto 1"]
```

But by getting the username by this mean, it can be of course edited by the user.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what code would be useful, my first guess would be trying to use some hook but I'm not sure how to add that answer to Flamingo table (first time trying these thing on wp) @RohitGupta

Comment: How does the username get on the contact form in the first place?  I dont get it.  Isnt it in the contact form that they create the username?

Comment: I just added more info. I think there is no way to make the field uneditable by the user, so maybe there is another way to associate the username to the form submitted @RohitGupta

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it using jQuery and the user will not be able to change it

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any resource that I can have a look? Sorry for the question, but I have no idea how can I interact with jQuery on wordpress. I would be glad to learn it

Comment: You can use Snippets plugin that allows you to inject code like php, css, jQuery, ajax directly into wordpress. Then you can assig an id to your field and someting like:

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){

Comment: jQuery(#myfiled).css({‘visibility’:’hidden’})

Comment: ;}) but keep in mind that you will find jquery code examples online using $ but for wordpress to understand jquery you must use ‘jQuery’ instead of $

Comment: Thanks for the details!! I will check it and learn how to implement it :)